# MySQL query to find latest 3 dates in a table

Tags: mysql, date

My table actually looks like this:

```
date           value
2015-06-27     8088.15
2015-06-27     8083.25
2015-06-27     8068.25
2015-06-24     8246.45
2015-06-24     8343.55
2015-06-24     8232.35
2015-06-24     8564.65
2015-06-23     8354.75
2015-06-23     8455.25
2015-06-23     8451.45
2015-06-22     8343.55
2015-06-22     8345.75
2015-06-21     8023.75
2015-06-21     8029.85
2015-06-20     8023.95
```

I want to query latest 3 dates from a table like this. The output I am expecting is:

```
2015-06-27
2015-06-24
2015-06-23
```

The purpose of this is to find out the max(value) and min(value) for last 3 days. The dates in the table are dates of week days but there can be holidays and every day can have indefinite number of rows.

How can I query 3 latest dates from table?
I tried this `select date from table_name order by date desc`. This is not giving the right output I am looking for.

Comment: bugfixer that will return first 3 rows of above table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the unique dates and then use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select date
from (select distinct date from table t) d
order by date desc
limit 3;
```

Comment: nice answer Gordon. Also, consider an index on date if appropriate, so as to avoid table scan

Comment: I think this ignores the 'purpose'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT date
     , MAX(value) max_val
     , MIN(value) min_val
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP  
    BY date 
 ORDER 
    BY date DESC 
 LIMIT 3;
+------------+---------+---------+
| date       | max_val | min_val |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 2015-06-27 | 8088.15 | 8068.25 |
| 2015-06-24 | 8564.65 | 8232.35 |
| 2015-06-23 | 8455.25 | 8354.75 |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, That helped a lot.

Comment: Only some? What sense does it not make?

Comment: That was the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use below Query:

```
select `date` from (select distinct `date` from table t1) d
order by `date` desc limit 3;
```

Comment: yes Distinct is not a function, so we can ignore the brackets .